# ES6: If class has method?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have a class with a method that calls other methods:

```
class MyClass {
  build(methods) {
    methods.forEach((method) => {
      if (this.method) {
        this.method();
      }
    });
  }

  stuff() {}
  moreStuff() {}
}

const a = MyClass();
a.build(['stuff', 'moreStuff']);
```

I haven't been able to find any reference on any special methods for classes. My first thought was to use `hasOwnProperty` (however eslint nags me that I shouldn't use it within the class). The approach above wouldn't work reliably as classes have built-in functions.

I was also looking at [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) as possibly being my saving grace, but I could really use some guidance on what is the best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Show us how you intend to call `build`, please

Comment: "*no reference on any special methods for classes*" - that's because classes are nothing special, and don't need any special methods. They're just constructor function with `.prototype` objects as always (though their prototype methods are not enumerable).

Comment: @Bergi I understand, they are just syntactic sugar, but I was really hoping they would have some cool introspection methods. I've updated my code. I'm guessing I should refactor and separate the `build` method into a function, and then use some kind of `Reflect`.

Comment: All the cool introspection you need is available for arbitrary objects, not just classes.

Comment: Thanks for the example. So you just want `build` to call all methods whose names were passed as an array?

Comment: @Bergi Correct, this is like a factory of some sort. Should probably separate. If I should do that, then would I just use MyClass.hasOwnProperty in the factory? It seems they don't want you to do introspection within the class itself.

Comment: `MyClass.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, but that doesn't work for inherited properties of course. But I still didn't really understand the use case. Wouldn't a factory method be static?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not super comfortable with all the terminology, this use case scenario just seems like a factory used for building classes, only it's for methods. I feel like my approach has to be wrong, it doesn't feel super right :)

Comment: The method you've shown has nothing to do with a factory for building classes? Or do you mean for building class instances? Yes, it does feel weird. Maybe you should ask a new question with a complete use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
build (methodnames) {
    for (const methodname of methodnames) {
        if (typeof this[methodname] == "function") {
            this[methodname]();
        }
    }
}
```

There's nothing special about classes - and in fact you should ignore them. If you want to call some method, the only thing that is important is that there is a function as a property value. It doesn't matter whether the method is an own property of the prototype object of the class that created the instance.

Comment: Would it be an anti-pattern to have this build method within the class, should I separate it into another function?

Comment: `build` sounds like a `static` method to me (i.e. `var newInstance = MyClass.build(…)`), but the way you've written it (or I wrote it in my answer), it's just an instance method, and that's totally fine in the class

Comment: Thanks! That gives me the confidence to move forward. I will have to read more on all this later, just wanted to out the new class feature.